# Sitecore doesn't render any field types anymore

Tags: sitecore, rendering

After a deploy to our Acceptance environment, templates in sitecore seem to be broken. We have installed them back with an item package from a working environment and did a revert on the /sitecore/templates/system tree.

We didn't notice any difficulties here, but when we try to edit with a rich text editor, we see the raw values. Even a tree list is rendered as a single line text field.

Next to that, the /sitecore/templates/system/templates/template item does not contain any fields.

Since we are on an acceptance environment, we cannot revert the entire database in case of data loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not think I entirely understand your issue, can you please be more specific and give us more details? You say templates are broken, but in what way exactly?Can you try reproducing that to ensure it happens again?

If you see everything as a text value, that happens because of you have Raw values in View tab switch on.

[image]

Comment: Hi Marti, the raw values are checked off, there is missing some rendering it seems which makes all values render as guid. The link field, tree list field, everything is as raw value displayed.

Comment: Any screenshot or some other sort of hint for us to guess on that would be helpful

Comment: Too bad my reputation is too low to provide a screenshot :(, our team decided to restore a back-up of databases to solve the problem. Seems the problem is located deep into the master database of sitecore.